# Download failing in every browser on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, download

I tried Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. All are failing to download a 22 MB file;

https://netfabb.azurewebsites.net/upload/download.php/head_fixed.stl?job=972b336f4c40403faf7769a80566645b

It can download up to 19.7 MB and then it stops and says:

> failed-network error

I **disabled the firewall**, but to no avail. I reinstalled Chrome , deleted temporary files, but again to no avail.

I tried downloading through the Chrome download manager plugin, but still I got the same error.

I do not have any antivirus either.

I observed I can download a 25 MB video from YouTube using [KeepVid](http://keepvid.com/) successfully.

But for this particular it is failing. What is the reason and what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetching it with `Invoke-WebRequest` (shorthanded to `wget` from powershell:

```
wget [url] -outfile [fname]
```

If you omit the `-outfile` parameter, it saves as a file object on the pipeline, and you can analyse it to your heart's content.